# Infinite scroll in ionic lab doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

Why the infinite scroll doesn't work? It appears the load bar but doesn't charge the other elements. It's my first time with ionic lab and I don't know very well the language.

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
      var page = 2;

       $http.get("endpoint where I canfound the data" + page).success(function(data, status) {
                page = page + 1;
                mergeArrays($scope.corsi, data);
                $ionicScrollDelegate.resize()
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");

        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          // log error
          alert('error lettura corsi');
        });

  };
```

The html page:

```
 <ion-content>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
        <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-repeat="corso in corsi"> 
                    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="sceltaCorso(corso.course_id)" href="#/app/singleCourse">
                      <img src={{corso.course_introimage}}>
                      <h2>{{corso.name}}</h2>
                      <h4>{{corso.short_description}}</h4>
                      <h5>{{corso.course_author}}</h5>
                    </a>
                </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
         <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()"></ion-infinite-scroll> 
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```